# How to put a CountDownTimer in a loop?

Tags: loops, kotlin, countdowntimer

So I'm currently working on an app that will perform a task that will be designed depending on the input provided by the user in a file. From the inputs, the app will get an ArrayList of String in which its size will be used to determine the number of repetition of the loop.

The task is to hide an ImageView and two buttons for a specific duration and then making it visible again (using CountDownTimer). While it is visible, the buttons get the response from the user when they click either one and store a value depending on the button clicked. After a certain duration the ImageView and the buttons will be invisible again.

The loop will be carrying out functions that will perform the task. The codes that I have right now without the loop are as follows:

```
    val timer3 = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            visible() //ImageView and buttons to be visible
            btnX.setOnClickListener {
                val intentResultActivity = Intent(this@TaskActivity, ResultActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intentResultActivity) //Go to the next activity
            }
            btnO.setOnClickListener {
                val intentResultActivity = Intent(this@TaskActivity, ResultActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intentResultActivity) //Go to the next activity
            }
        }

        override fun onTick(p2: Long) {
            invisible() //ImageView and buttons to be invisible
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(SettingsActivity.pic3)) //Set the image 
        }
    }

    val timer2 = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            visible() //ImageView and buttons to be visible
            btnX.setOnClickListener {
                timer3.start() //Start the next timer
            }
            btnO.setOnClickListener {
                timer3.start() //Start the next timer
            }
        }

        override fun onTick(p1: Long) {
            invisible() //ImageView and buttons to be invisible
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(SettingsActivity.pic2)) //Set the image 
        }
    }

    val timer = object: CountDownTimer(5000,1000){
        override fun onFinish() {
            visible() //ImageView and buttons to be visible
            btnX.setOnClickListener {
                timer2.start() //Start the next timer
            }
            btnO.setOnClickListener {
                timer2.start() //Start the next timer
            }
        }

        override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
            invisible() //ImageView and buttons to be invisible
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(SettingsActivity.pic1)) //Set the image 
        }
    }
```

The looping code that I did below will perform the last CountDownTimer and skips the rest.

```
    for (i in 0 until SettingsActivity.picArray.size) {
        if (i<(SettingsActivity.picArray.size-1)) {
            timerLoopBlank(i)
        }
    }
```

Below are the functions that carries out the task in the loop:

```
    private fun timerLoopBlank (i:Int) {
        val timerBlank = object: CountDownTimer(5000,1000){
            override fun onFinish() {
                visible()
                timerLoopAnswer()
            }

            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                invisible()
                imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(SettingsActivity.picArray[i]))
            }
        }
        timerBlank.start()
    }

    fun timerLoopAnswer () {
        val timerAnswer = object: CountDownTimer(5000,1000){
            override fun onFinish() {

            }

            override fun onTick(p1: Long) {
                btnX.setOnClickListener {
                    answerArray.add('X')
                }
                btnO.setOnClickListener {
                    answerArray.add('O')
                }
            }
        }
        timerAnswer.start()
    }

    fun invisible(){
        imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        btnX.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        btnO.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    fun visible(){
        imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnX.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnO.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

I think the earlier CountDownTimers are skipped due to the onTick parameter. How can I perform the loop and do not skip the earlier CountDownTimers? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You are creating multiple objects of `CountDownTimer`. Just create its object in the class body and in `onFinish()` do `timer.start()`

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? I'm sorry but I'm really new to this.